# Unable to connect to SMTP server using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following is my script to connect to SMTP server and sending mail.

```
from smtplib import SMTP
import datetime

debuglevel = 0

smtp = SMTP()
smtp.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
smtp.connect('smtp.gmail.com', 26)
smtp.login('ashwini.jena@gmail.com', 'Pa***wd')

from_addr = "Ashwin<ashwini.jena@gmail.com>"
to_addr = "foo@bar.com"

subj = "hello"
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime( "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" )

message_text = "Hello\nThis is a mail from your server\n\nBye\n"

msg = "From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\nDate: %s\n\n%s"%( from_addr, to_addr, subj, date, message_text )

smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg)
smtp.quit()
```

But it throws the following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Bidhoo.py", line 15, in <module>
    smtp.connect('smtp.gmail.com', 26)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 317, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 288, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 424, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 415, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Please help me to find the root cause of this error. Also could anybody share alternate code to connect to SMTP ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get better answers to your questions, please read and take to heart the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) article.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that this is failing on the smtp.connect line? You can verify this by running the script line by line in the Python interpreter.

The reason this is failing is because the port number is incorrect. Instead of 26, try 587 and see what happens.

```
smtp.connect('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

As for alternative scripts, I found a few scripts by Googling. Here's [one](http://segfault.in/2010/12/sending-gmail-from-python/)

Comment: Same error observed by using above.[ changed the port to 587]